# Retain several mp3 sounds using AVPlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, avplayer, system-sounds

I am working on an interactive children's book and for that purpose I've built a sliding windows of sounds. For sounds .caf I haven't have any problem to load different sounds in memory because I've used SystemSoundID:

```
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(),(CFStringRef)@"name_sound", CFSTR("caf"), NULL), &systemSoundIDs[0]);
```

However I also have mp3 files and for that kind of sounds I can't use the way I explained before (mp3 is not supported by systemSoundID). Is it possible to do that using AVPlayer? Is there any way to load in memory several mp3 sounds at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you cannot play 2 sounds at the same time on an iPhone if the files are both MP3 or AAC encoded, because there is only one hardware path for real time decoding of these compressed formats. You can play multiple files that are already decompressed, so one thing you can do is simply read the AAC or MP3 file ahead of time and save it as an uncompressed .caf. You will need to be careful to manage your disk space, but that is just the price to be paid.